# Sort SQL by range of date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a small self made gallery which im still working on it:
http://springbreak.enteratenorte.com

And the SQL structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'en_albums' (
    'id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    'name' text,
    'folder' text,
    'description' text,
    'hits' int(11) default NULL,
    'datecreated' date default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=372 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=372 ;
```

And I have around 300 albums, so I would to sort the most popular which is simple with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM en_albums ORDER BY hits DESC
```

But I would like to know how can I do the same thing, but only sort album not older than 6 month, or 1 month, or 1 year, this is a sample of the lines in my albums:

```
INSERT INTO 'en_albums' 
  ('id', 'name', 'folder', 
   'description', 'hits', 'datecreated') 
VALUES 
 (1, 'Friends Picture', 'en-fotosdeamigos', 
  'Pictures sent by our visitors', 1514, '2005-07-19');
```

Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: If an album *is* older than 6 months, 1 year, etc, do you want to show it in the list at all, or exclude it totally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to get albums created within a time period you can use

```
SELECT * FROM en_albums WHERE datecreated > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ORDER BY hits DESC
```

This will only return items which have a datecreated greater than 6 months ago. You can change the `6` and `MONTH` part to be what you want. You can replace `MONTH` with any of the following:

- MICROSECOND
- SECOND
- MINUTE
- HOUR
- DAY
- WEEK
- MONTH
- QUARTER
- YEAR

Comment: This assumes a particular answer to the question I asked in the comments section.  Without an answer to that question you really should be specifying your assumptions.

Comment: @Dems I just went with the hunch that this is what they meant, but I agree this could be wrong (I did upvote your comment!) so I've added that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two answers to you question.  @Tim took one answer *(exclude albums older than your specified limit)*.  This gives an alternative...

- First, list all albums less than 6 months old
  *(For those albums, list those with the most hits first)*
- After those albums, cary on the list with all albums over 6 months old
  *(For those albums, list the most recent album first)*

This does just that...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  en_albums
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN datecreated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN 0    ELSE 1 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN datecreated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) THEN hits ELSE 0 END DESC,
  datecreated DESC
```

Any album less than 6 months old will be sorted by...

- `0, hits, datecreated`

Any album more than 6 months old will be sorted by...

- `1, 0, datecreated`